# localStorage variable in clicking game adds text instead of numbers to score, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html

So I was creating a clicking game with JavaScript and ran into the following issue. I'm defining a variable to a `localStorage` item, and every time I click the button that should add one to the score it adds one to the end of the text. For example: [*before click: (1) after click: (11)*] Why does it do this?

My code is provided in the image below:

[The Code (Html)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVmxJ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Progman the app wouldn't let me copy the code

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve the data from local storage, you need to convert it into a number, like this:

```js
var Clicks = Number(localStorage.getItem('mystats');
```

This happens because local storage can only store strings. So, when you get the number of clicks from local storage on line 2, if the number of clicks is, for example, 1, it returns `'1'`. `'1' + 1 == '11'`, which is why this is happening. Here is another example:

```js
const x = '1';

console.log(x + 1); // logs '11'
console.log(Number(x) + 1); // logs 2
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

You should convert the result of `localStorage.getItem` to a Number before incrementing it, like this:

```
var Clicks = Number(localStorage.getItem("mystats"));
Clicks = Clicks + 1;
```

More details:

I think you are facing this issue because `localStorage` saves all the values as `string`.

For example: if you run the following command in the console:

```
localStorage.setItem("test", 123);
```

and then:

```
localStorage.getItem("test");
```

the value you will get in return will be:

```
"123"
```

If you want to get the value as a number you would want to convert the return of `localStorage.getItem` to `Number`:

```
const testValue = localStorage.getItem("test");
const testNumber = Number(testValue);
```

or a one-liner:

```
Number(localStorage.getItem("test"));
```